# Where delete the parameter that references the UART serial port (ttyAMA0)?

Tags: uart, cmdline.txt

I have to use a sensor and one of the steps asked me to delete the parameter that references the UART serial port (ttyAMA0) in cmdline.txt, does it mean that I have to delete this part `console=serial0,115200` from my cmdline.txt :

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> one of the steps asked me to delete the parameter that references the UART serial port (ttyAMA0) in cmdline.txt, does it mean that I have to delete this part console=serial0,115200 from my cmdline.txt

Yes.  This is to stop the kernel from using that for console output (boot and warning/error messages).

Make sure that file remains *all one line*.  Parameters should be separated by spaces, but key/value pairs should not contain any (i.e., `key=value`, not `key = value`).

Answer (score 0):

You could delete `serial0` BUT the preferable way to manage changes is through `raspi-config`. This just modifies the same files, but does it in a standard way across different models.

You don't say which model you are using, or which sensor. Presumably this uses serial, so you may have to modify any code which accesses it. Also the serial port is disabled by default on the Pi3. See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I am going to connect the shield connection bridge and e-health platform with my Pi 3, and I am going to use Temperature sensor, please check this link "3.2 Enabling Interfaces" step number 7: https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shields-connection-bridge#step4 .. I deleted  `console=serial0,115200 ` from cmdline, I read the link that you send but I do not really know what should I do ? I think they ask me to disable the serial console and that is what I did, did I miss something ? please I _need_ you help

Comment: @RMSH You should paste additional information into your question, not in comments. It is not possible to say what you should do from a (poorly formatted) tutorial with hundreds of steps. You need to tell us what you have ACTUALLY done. I glanced through the tutorial, and this mentions swapping UART on Bluetooth. I do not think this is a good idea, but that depends on you (I have not tried this). I note the tutorial says "Difficulty Level: Expert". I personally wouldn't bother with something to connect Arduino shields to a Pi, I would just make direct connections for things I actually use.

Comment: @RMSH This seems to be a totally new question, which was just originally about disabling serial console.